# git list all available commands

Tags: git, ubuntu

Is there command which can show me list of all available commands in GIT? There is `git help` but it shows:

```
usage: git [--version] [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path]
           [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects]
           [--bare] [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>]
           [-c name=value] [--help]
           <command> [<args>]

The most commonly used git commands are:
   add        Add file contents to the index
   bisect     Find by binary search the change that introduced a bug
   branch     List, create, or delete branches
   checkout   Checkout a branch or paths to the working tree
   clone      Clone a repository into a new directory
   commit     Record changes to the repository
   diff       Show changes between commits, commit and working tree, etc
   fetch      Download objects and refs from another repository
   grep       Print lines matching a pattern
   init       Create an empty git repository or reinitialize an existing one
   log        Show commit logs
   merge      Join two or more development histories together
   mv         Move or rename a file, a directory, or a symlink
   pull       Fetch from and merge with another repository or a local branch
   push       Update remote refs along with associated objects
   rebase     Forward-port local commits to the updated upstream head
   reset      Reset current HEAD to the specified state
   rm         Remove files from the working tree and from the index
   show       Show various types of objects
   status     Show the working tree status
   tag        Create, list, delete or verify a tag object signed with GPG

See 'git help <command>' for more information on a specific command.
```

And I want just list without description.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Try:

```
git help -a
```

---

Comment: Its not 100% what I've expected but its better than what I found +1

Comment: @skowron-line: It's a list of all available git commands without descriptions. Isn't that what you asked for?

Comment: Yes this is what I asked for.

Comment: +1 Very nice :) The section at the bottom of "git commands available from elsewhere on your $PATH" is particularly useful.

Comment: @MarkLongair - What is the git commands from elsewhere? I don't see it on msysgit

Comment: @manojlds: They are other commands outside of your git installation that you can call through git because they begin git-. If you don't have any such commands then you won't see that section. It's not important.

Comment: Note, you can do `git help help`. Just in case one doesn't remember the the specific option.

Answer (score 9):

As @CharlesBailey already suggested, `git help -a` is a great way to list all of the subcommands that git offers. However, if you want to remove some of the formatting that git prints, that can be done too:

The easiest way to get a list of all git subcommands is as follows:

```
git help -a | grep "^  [a-z]" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -v "^$"
```

This takes the output of `git help -a`, selects only the lines that are indented, converts spaces to newline characters, and then removes the empty lines.

Why would you want something like this? A common reason for wanting to list the subcommands of a command is to enable autocompletion in Bash:

```
complete -W "$(git help -a | grep "^  [a-z]")" git
```

Now, when you type `git br` and press `TAB`, it autocompletes to `git branch`. Enjoy!

Comment: From the Git Documentation, here is another way to easily enable [Git Command Auto-Completion](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Basics-Tips-and-Tricks#Auto-Completion) if you use bash shell.

Comment: @AndresM the link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `--listcmds` argument to `git`:

```
$ git --list-cmds=main,nohelpers | sort
add
am
annotate
apply
archive
bisect
...
```

The [tab completion referred to in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7871300/971090) seems to use the following to generate its list (found in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git`):

```
git --list-cmds=main,others,alias,nohelper
```

Do note the caveat in the [documentation of this parameter](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---list-cmdsgroupgroup82308203):

> This is an internal/experimental option and may change or be removed in the future.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using linux (BASH). You can try

```
`$ git [TAB] [TAB]`
```

Then I got something like this:

```
$ git 
add                 fetch               rebase 
am                  fetchavs            reflog 
annotate            filter-branch       relink 
apply               format-patch        remote 
archive             fsck                repack 
bisect              gc                  replace 
blame               get-tar-commit-id   request-pull 
br                  grep                reset 
branch              gui                 revert 
bundle              help                rm 
checkout            imap-send           shortlog 
cherry              init                show 
cherry-pick         instaweb            show-branch 
ci                  log                 st 
citool              log1                stage 
clean               merge               stash 
clone               mergetool           status 
co                  mv                  submodule 
commit              name-rev            svn 
config              notes               tag 
describe            pull                whatchanged 
diff                push                
difftool            pushav
```

Comment: I imagine you will find under the hood that this uses `git help -a`.

Comment: This is not a complete list of available commands, e.g. `ls-remote` is missing.

Comment: Don't you have to enable [Git command Auto-Completion](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Basics-Tips-and-Tricks#Auto-Completion) first for this to actually work?

Answer (score 1):

To list git commands, inluding git commands available from elsewhere on your $PATH

```
git help -a
```

---

To list user-configured aliases use

```
git aliases
```

---

Answer (score 1):

With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), "[`git help -a`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1f3c5f39e0582b9538106a7da38a5af89e5785a4/Documentation/git-help.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-help#Documentation/git-help.txt---all))</sup> has new options which helps filter/clarify the list of commands.

See [commit 93de1b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93de1b6999898079f521afd73d6a4ae9d5f9aaea), [commit 1ce5901](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ce590133b545aa735683f46003d12df624d67af), [commit 503cdda](https://github.com/git/git/commit/503cddacb63b9a37d063de5b11ac188de822e06f), [commit 5e8068b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e8068b74df8d0c58042a3ffe1c09dbffbbc63f7), [commit d7f817d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d7f817d376134ec09e6804cdb6e3d062e3308eb9), [commit 6fb427a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6fb427abbb06236546c0d5b873e580b0a6fdb414), [commit bf7eed7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf7eed75b90756c960da4828476b669a358df05b), [commit cd87ce7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd87ce7d0def6b6efeb1ae688bde217a0a47c9eb), [commit 4bf5cda](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4bf5cdab8e1c9ad884748c02669287ea1fae05d9) (21 Feb 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1f3c5f3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f3c5f39e0582b9538106a7da38a5af89e5785a4), 09 Mar 2022)</sup>

> ### [`help`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ce590133b545aa735683f46003d12df624d67af): add `--no-[external-commands|aliases]` for use with `--all`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Add the ability to only emit git's own usage information under `--all`.
>
> This also allows us to extend the `"test_section_spacing"` tests added in a preceding commit to test "[`git help --all`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1ce590133b545aa735683f46003d12df624d67af/Documentation/git-help.txt#L48)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-help#Documentation/git-help.txt---all))</sup> output.
>
> Previously we could not do that, as the tests might find a git-* command in the "$PATH", which would make the output differ from one setup to another.

`git help` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1ce590133b545aa735683f46003d12df624d67af/Documentation/git-help.txt#L11):

> ### `'git help' [-a|--all] [--[no-]verbose] [--[no-]external-commands] [--[no-]aliases]`

`git help` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1ce590133b545aa735683f46003d12df624d67af/Documentation/git-help.txt#L51-L58):

> ### `--no-external-commands`
>
> When used with `--all`, exclude the listing of external "`git-*`"
> commands found in the `$PATH`.
>
> ### `--no-aliases`
>
> When used with `--all`, exclude the listing of configured
> aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://thenucleargeeks.com/2020/01/20/git-commands-cheat-sheet/

```
Windows: Use Chocolatey and in powershell type

choco install git
Linux:

ubuntu: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git -redhat: sudo yum install git -h
Mac OS:

install Homebrew and Xcode
Set a user name which can be seen or associated with every commit

git config --global user.name "nuclear geeks"
Set a user email which can we seen or associated with every commit

git config --global user.email "nucleargeeks18@gmail.com"
Clone an existing repository

git clone url
Check the modified file in working directory.

git status
Add a modified file to staging area.

git add <file_name>
Add all the modified file to staging area

git add . 
Commit message

git commit -m "commit_message"
Difference between working area and staging

git diff <file_name>
Difference between working area and last commit or repository

git diff HEAD <file_name>
Difference between staging area and repository

git diff --staged 
git diff --staged <file_name>
List all your branches

git branch 
Create new branch

git checkout -b <branch_name>
Push the branch to origin

git push origin <branch_name>
Switch to another branch

git checkout <branch_name>
Merge branches

git merge <branch_name>
Backout File, If you want to move your file from stage area to working or unstage area

git reset HEAD <file_name>
Discard changes in working directory

git checkout <file_name>
Delete file

git rm <file_name>
Rename a file

git mv <current_name> <new_name>
Move a file

git mv <file_name> <dir_name>
Git alias, renaming command to new name

git config -global alias. <short_command> <"long command">
Find hidden file

git ls -al 
Stash your changes

git stash
To apply your changed from stash

git stash apply
To delete your stash from the list

git stash drop
To list your stash list

git stash list 
To apply the changes and delete from the listt

git stash pop
Git stash with message

git stash save "msg"
Find change done in specific index

git stash show stash@{id}
Apply

git stash apply stash@{id}
Tag creation

git tag <tag_name>
Annotated tag creation

git tag -a <tag_name>
Push tag to remote

git push origin <tag_name>
List all the tags

git tag --list
Delete tags

git tag --delete <tag_name>
Create a branch from the tag

git checkout -b <branch_name> <tagname>
Create a tag from past commit

git tag <tag_name> <reference_of_commit>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an ancient question and it has already been answered, but I recently ran into this conundrum while looking for some of the manipulators and saw that they weren't being listed by the bash completions for git.

Passing the arguments:

> list-mainporcelain,list-ancillaryinterrogators,list-ancillarymanipulators,list-plumbingmanipulators,list-plumbinginterrogators,list-synchingrepositories,list-synchelpers,list-purehelpers

to "git --list-cmds" will produce a list of every command git has available as seen in the example below.

```
 git --list-cmds=list-mainporcelain,list-ancillaryinterrogators,list-ancillarymanipulators,list-plumbingmanipulators,list-plumbinginterrogators,list-synchingrepositories,list-synchelpers,list-purehelpers|sort -u
```

**I've also written a patch for the bash completions as well so when you type out git [tab][tab] it will actually show all the commands available even if not every one of them has argument completion for the specific command.**

```patch
--- /tmp/bash-completions-git   2024-01-16 13:30:01.068501500 -0500
+++ /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git  2024-01-16 13:55:30.857304100 -0500
@@ -1131,11 +1131,16 @@
    return 1
 }
 
-__git_all_commands=
+
+#__git_all_commands=
 __git_compute_all_commands ()
 {
-   test -n "$__git_all_commands" ||
-   __git_all_commands=$(__git --list-cmds=main,others,alias,nohelpers)
+   test -n "$__git_all_commands" || (
+   # Their original code
+   # __git_all_commands=$(__git --list-cmds=main,others,alias,nohelpers)
+   # my much better command that actually gets ALL git commands.
+   __git_all_commands=$(git help -a | grep -P '^\s+[a-z]' | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u)
+   )
 }
 
 # Lists all set config variables starting with the given section prefix,
@@ -3562,13 +3567,13 @@
            then
                __gitcomp "$GIT_TESTING_PORCELAIN_COMMAND_LIST"
            else
-               local list_cmds=list-mainporcelain,others,nohelpers,alias,list-complete,config
+               local list_cmds=list-mainporcelain,others,nohelpers,alias,list-complete,config,list-ancillaryinterrogators,list-ancillarymanipulators,list-plumbingmanipulators,list-plumbinginterrogators
 
                if test "${GIT_COMPLETION_SHOW_ALL_COMMANDS-}" = "1"
                then
                    list_cmds=builtins,$list_cmds
                fi
-               __gitcomp "$(__git --list-cmds=$list_cmds)"
+               __gitcomp "$(__git --list-cmds=$list_cmds|sort -u)"
            fi
            ;;
        esac
```

It's quite handy when you forget things like ls-tree.

```
$ git       
Display all 116 possibilities? (y or n)
add                 commit-tree         gitk                merge-tree          replace             submodule 
am                  config              gitweb              mktag               request-pull        switch 
annotate            count-objects       grep                mktree              rerere              symbolic-ref 
apply               describe            gui                 multi-pack-index    reset               tag 
archive             diagnose            hash-object         mv                  restore             unpack-file 
bisect              diff                help                name-rev            revert              unpack-objects 
blame               diff-files          index-pack          notes               rev-list            update-index 
branch              diff-index          init                pack-objects        rev-parse           update-ref 
bugreport           difftool            instaweb            pack-redundant      rm                  var 
bundle              diff-tree           lfs                 pack-refs           scalar              verify-commit 
cat-file            fast-export         log                 prune               send-email          verify-pack 
checkout            fast-import         ls-files            prune-packed        shortlog            verify-tag 
checkout-index      fetch               ls-remote           pull                show                version 
cherry              filter-branch       ls-tree             push                show-branch         whatchanged 
cherry-pick         for-each-ref        maintenance         range-diff          show-index          worktree 
citool              for-each-repo       merge               read-tree           show-ref            write-tree 
clean               format-patch        merge-base          rebase              sparse-checkout     
clone               fsck                merge-file          reflog              stage               
commit              gc                  merge-index         remote              stash               
commit-graph        get-tar-commit-id   mergetool           repack              status
```

Answer (score -3):

command for clone url: `git clone url`

command to check status: `git status`

command to add file: `git add pom.xml` `git add src/`

command to commit code with message: `git commit -m "initial version"`

command to push: `git push -u origin master`

command to clear git terminal: `clear`

command to checkout different branch: `git checkout -b branch-name`

command to add file: `git add src/main/java/com/rest/mongo/UserExample.java`

command to pull updates from different branch: `git pull origin develop`

command to push through upstream: `git push --set-upstream origin 11111feature-234`

steps to merge your branch to develop/master branch: `git checkout -b develop`
`git merge your-branch-name`

**for reference use below link:(step by step explanation)**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzZj-bnjX6w&t=17s