# How remove directory/files from all branches in a repo? (as new commit in each)

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to remove a directory from every branch in a repo? I know I could manually (one at a time) check out each branch, delete the directory and its files, commit, push and then repeat for each branch.

I would prefer to have one command (or script) that can do this across all the branches of the repo.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing built in, but the [plumbing command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39847781/1256452) `git for-each-ref` allows you to iterate over all branch names:

```
git for-each-ref --format '%(refname:short)' refs/heads
```

Using this you can write a simple script that will `git checkout` each branch, `git rm` the file or files in question, and `git commit` the result.  (You can then push all the results in one `git push`: there's no need to push each one as you go.)