# How to use Git credential store on WSL (Ubuntu on Windows)?

Tags: git, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've tried following these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40312117/21728 which basically do this:

```
sudo apt-get install libsecret-1-0 libsecret-1-dev
cd /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret
sudo make
git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret
```

But when I do any network operation, I get this error:

```
** (process:7902): CRITICAL **: could not connect to Secret Service: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

That's logical I guess as there is indeed no X11 display.

How to make Git credentials caching work on Ubuntu on Windows (WSL)?

Comment: Helpful tutorial: https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/git_credential_manager_with_windows_subsystem_for_linux.html

Comment: Microsoft has an official tutorial on this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-git

Comment: The Microsoft tutorial uses "git-credential-manager-core.exe" instead of "git-credential-manager.exe". Which means you will be getting a warning that there was a rename ( https://aka.ms/gcm/rename ). I fixed this warning by using "git-credential-manager.exe" instead.

Comment: The microsoft tutorial has been updated for git >= v2.39.0 too now.

Answer (score 214):

If you installed Git for Windows there is a windows integrated credential manager installed on your system.

You can run windows executables from WSL as found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/interop#invoking-windows-binaries-from-wsl).

To use it you can run the following command (assuming that your git for windows is installed on C:\Program Files\Git, and is version < v2.36.1)

```
git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-credential-manager.exe"
```

For the latest paths, see the Microsoft tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-git

Comment: This is about Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), not MSysGit. You can't install Git for Windows inside of the WSL.

Comment: Ok, you can´t install, but you can use the windows executables from WSL, so you can use the credential helper from git for windows on git running on WSL. This configuration is copied from my own machine.

Comment: `git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-wincred.exe"`  This is the command I use. If you have a path with a space you need to escape it and also put it in quotes.

Comment: I had to install the Creators Update for Windows before this worked for me. I also had to use this exact string in my .gitconfig:
    "/mnt/c/Program\\ Files\\ \\\(x86\\\)/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-credential-wincred.exe"

Comment: This has been so useful. Now I don't need both `Git Bash` and `WSL Bash` open to work on a repo.

One question, what is the difference between `git-credential-wincred.exe` and `git-credential-manager.exe`?

Comment: git-credential-wincred.exe is an older implementation, it will be better to use git-credential-manager.exe today.

Comment: @CarlosBeppler Is there an explanation of the difference anywhere?

Comment: [git-credential-manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) is implemented by Microsoft in a separate repository. In that repository there are the following message: "The Git Credential Manager for Windows (GCM) provides secure Git credential storage for Windows. It's the successor to the Windows Credential Store for Git (git-credential-winstore), which is no longer maintained. "

Comment: Actually you don't even need to have git installed on Windows. You may just as well unzip the archive (found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/latest)) anywhere on your linux distribution, give *.exe files executable permissions and then set `credential.helper` config value accordingly (as shown in this answer). Note: .NET Framework 4.5.1 or greater is required.

Comment: Don't need to use Windows git for WSL

Comment: Yes, you do not need, but the credential manager of Windows git can be integrated with The WSL git,  só you do not need to replicate your credentials.

Comment: I think this should be `git-credential-manager-core`, as `git-credential-manager` has been deprecated, [according to Microsoft](http://microsoft.github.io/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/)

Comment: Yes, thanks, I'll update the instructions.

Comment: The path is again updated in the current version 2.36.1 of "Git for Windows":
`git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-credential-manager-core.exe"`

Comment: @UmarGhouse, I think there might be a mix-up of news here, it's my understanding that "git-credential-manager-core" is actually the one being deprecated just in name ( https://aka.ms/gcm/rename ). If you go to the Windows folder for the git credential manager, you can see there's two credential manager executables (one with the *-core.exe and the other without). The versioning seems the same between both. So it's my understanding that they are still keeping the "core.exe" version for backwards compatibility only.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Esteban, I'll update the information according to the new docs.

Answer (score 67):

## TL;DR

I've created [a script that does this for you](https://gist.github.com/RichardBronosky/9ab50abb8698e02341629db21e5fa6bf#file-configure-git-credential-hellper-sh). I use it with my Chef orchestration.

## Locate or install git-credential-manager.exe

1. Open `cmd.exe` and call `where git-credential-manager.exe`

   - If it returns a path, GREAT. Move on to converting the path.
   - If not...
2. In `cmd.exe` call `where git.exe`

   - If it does not return a path, the next step is to install the Credential Manager alone
   - If it does return a path, it will be something like:
   - `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe`
   - Let's drop the everything after the next to last slash and change it like so:
   - `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-credential-manager.exe`
   - If that exists, GREAT. Move on to converting the path.
   - Otherwise...
3. Install *Credential Manager* from [Microsoft's git repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/latest), and then use `where` again to get the path.

## Convert the path from DOS to Linux

We need to:

1. Replace the `C:\` with `/mnt/c/`
2. Flip the slashes from `\` to `/`
3. Escape spaces (and parenthesis if there are any) with double backslashes `\\`

So...

- `"C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-credential-manager.exe"` becomes...
- `"/mnt/c/Program\\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager.exe"`

My script above has a function for doing just that

```sh
dos_path_to_linux(){
    sed -e 's?\\?/?g' -e' s?[cC]:?/mnt/c?' <<<"$1"
}
```

But, as [@12345ieee has since commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925964/how-to-use-git-credential-store-on-wsl-ubuntu-on-windows/51669404?noredirect=1#comment106869879_51669404), a `wslpath` utility has been added to [WSL build 17046](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes?redirectedfrom=MSDN#build-17046). It's worth checking out, but I don't have access to Windows at this time to verify. (Note that even though a usage statement is given in the release notes in my link, it seems that the command [doesn't currently include a usage statement](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2715), -h, etc.)

## Configure git

1. In `bash` call `git config --global credential.helper "<converted/path>"`

Comment: The script didn't work for me -- but doing the steps manually still did, so +1.

Comment: Quick point of clarity if "use Git credential store on WSL (Ubuntu on windows)" indicates 'within' to anyone instead of 'upon':  this works unless you are using a linux installation of git and ~/.gitconfig within Ubuntu where you can just do ```git config credential.helper store``` or better yet use ```git-credential-libsecret``` instead.

Comment: `git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager.exe"`

Comment: Since recent versions of WSL, there is a `wslpath` utility on the linux side that can convert paths automatically, call `wslpath path\to\convert` from the WSL shell and it'll make the conversion for you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @12345ieee! I have added that to my answer.

Comment: Ubuntu-specific solution by @scott-wade should be the correct answer here. Running the Windows exe from within WSL makes no sense if git is being run in the Ubuntu instance.

Comment: Running the Windows credential manager from WSL makes perfect sense. As the new GCM core (git-credential-manager-core.exe?) actually supports multi-factor auth on 3 major Git providers and the user is likely already logged in on the Windows provider. Something libsecret won't help you with.

Comment: This helped a lot but you should find the full path of git-credential-store in Windows since if you go without a custom install of git the paths will not be those ones. mine is located under /appdata/local/Programs

Answer (score 45):

Using Windows 10 and "WSL", I created a ~/.gitconfig file, but had mistyped the [credential] section label as [credentials].
I tried running git credential fill and then feeding its output to git credential approve, which might have worked, but I suspect not since it said "usage: git credential [fill|approve|reject]".
Finally, I simply ran:

```
$ git config --global credential.helper cache
```

and then did a git pull; when prompted for user and password I typed them as usual.  After that, it remembered it.  I found it had added the (correctly named) section to my ~/.gitconfig:

```
[credential]
        helper = cache
```

I edited that to provide a much longer timeout:

```
[credential]
        helper = cache --timeout=144000
```

And it all seems to be working nicely now.

Comment: This worked out nicely for me. Thanks for a great tip and have a +1 from me!

Comment: Perfect and simple solution for me, this timeout are in seconds?

Comment: Worked perfectly with VsCode + WSL2 under Windows 10. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

```
alias git=git.exe
```

Will simple use the git.exe from windows and its configurations

Comment: I struggled with a timeout when trying to run any git command to a remote repository hosted on Github. This alias eliminated the issue!

Comment: This is an incredibly simple and effective solution to the problem.

Comment: This was incredible simple and effective!!!

Comment: Works perfectly from CLI, but not from VSCode (continue asking for password)

Comment: Thank you. Works for me: VSCode + Windows 10 + WSL2

Answer (score 21):

All the answers are overly complicated to this point. And the git documentation does not really help, they link to reference material a lot so you need to follow 2-3 links to get the info you need!

1. You do not need to use Windows `git.exe` with WSL!  Use linux git `sudo apt install git-all` (I think it comes pre-installed with Ubuntu).
2. Then you can simply follow the instructions at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage.

### Summary

git supports 2 methods by default.  To see what methods you have installed, execute this command:

```
git help -a | grep credential
```

my result was:

```
   credential           Retrieve and store user credentials
   credential-cache     Helper to temporarily store passwords in memory
   credential-store     Helper to store credentials on disk
```

### How to for cache & store:

### [cache](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache)

@selkieTG covers this in their answer, including for completeness...

```
git config --global credential.helper "cache --timeout 30000"
```

will cache your password/token for 30,000 seconds (8 hrs 20min)

### [store](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store)

```
git config --global credential.helper "store"
```

will store plain text password/token in `~/.git-credentials`.

**Plain Text?!!** For WSL, I am absolutely OK with plain text here.  I enter credentials to run my Windows machine and I enter credentials to sign into WSL2.  Do I need to hide these?  Not really, it is more of a convenience on my dev box.

### [manager-core](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core)

If you really want to use `manager-core` you can install it in your [Ubuntu version](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core#linux-tarball-targz).  And then use it.

Comment: hopefully you also enter e pw for the disk encryption, otherwise your password may be exposed. Also, any malware can read it from `\\wsl$` Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

Consider [Microsoft GCM v2.1.1](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/releases) (May 2023), as it includes:

- Better browser detection inside of WS ([#1148](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/pull/1148), resolving [issue 878](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/issues/878): "for `wslview`: Browser authentication disabled if `DISPLAY` variable is not set")
- Better documentation on the GCM install paths in WSL ([#1168](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/pull/1168))

The installation is [described here](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/blob/d3ecd76ae17152403de4a1c7c6ec1389c3c64925/docs/wsl.md):

> Start by installing the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).
>
> Inside your WSL installation, run the following command to set GCM as the Git credential helper:
>
> ```
> git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-credential-manager.exe"
> ```
>
> Note: the location of git-credential-manager.exe may be different in your installation of Git for Windows.

This is now `git-credential-manager.exe`, [no longer `git-credential-manager-core.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68768432/6309) (since Git 2.39.0+, Dec. 2022, and [GCM v2.0.877](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/releases/tag/v2.0.877) (Nov. 2022), [PR 551](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/pull/551)).

And, as I [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60539792/6309), for a credential per repository:

```
git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true
```

---

As noted by [Loligans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2059761/loligans) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925964/how-to-use-git-credential-store-on-wsl-ubuntu-on-windows/76203319#comment134807197_76203319), regarding the location of that executable:

> If you don't know where your git executable location is and you are able to execute git on the command line then you can use the following command: [`git --exec-path`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---exec-pathltpathgt) which will give you the git executable location.
> This should help narrow down your search

(Although I had a [different opinion in 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928561/where-is-git-exe-located#comment78160842_45600651))
(I [mentioned `--exec-path` here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43432410/6309))

Comment: If you don't know where your git executable location is and you are able to execute `git` on the command line then you can use the following command: `git --exec-path` which will give you the `git` executable location. This should help narrow down your search

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you. Super easy to setup.

Answer (score 3):

It's already documented on vscode-docs:

---

#### Sharing Git credentials between Windows and WSL

If you use HTTPS to clone your repositories and **have a [credential helper configured](https://docs.github.com/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git) in Windows**, you can share this with WSL so that passwords you enter are persisted on both sides. (Note that this does not apply to using SSH keys.)

Just follow these steps:

1. Configure the credential manager on Windows by running the following in a **Windows command prompt** or **PowerShell**:

   ```
    git config --global credential.helper wincred
   ```
2. Configure WSL to use the same credential helper, but running the following in a **WSL terminal** (assuming you have `git` >= `v2.39.0`):

   ```bash
    git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-credential-manager.exe"
   ```

> To know the path for previous versions of `git`, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-git

Any password you enter when working with Git on the Windows side will now be available to WSL and vice versa.

---

Source:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/docs/remote/troubleshooting.md#sharing-git-credentials-between-windows-and-wsl

Comment: Note that the WSL side is now called just "git-credential-manager.exe". See  https://aka.ms/gcm/rename

Answer (score 2):

I have just recently updated to WSL2 and in my case the following wasn't working:

`"/mnt/c/Program\\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager.exe"`

What worked was the following:
`git config --global credential.helper "/c/Program\\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager.exe"`

Until I've removed `/mnt/` from the path I was getting a "not found" error.

From what I've investigated there's an issue with mounting windows drives in WSL2 after a clean Windows startup, more details here:
`https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4122`
And that was the most probable cause in my case.

Another reason for this can be a misconfiguration of root directory in `/etc/wsl.conf`

Comment: This answer only works for git < v2.36.1

Answer (score 0):

Download: (gcmcore-linux_amd64.2.0.567.18224.deb) https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/releases/tag/v2.0.567

Install:

```
sudo apt install gcmcore -y or 

sudo dpkg -i <path-to-package.deb>   (gcmcore-linux_amd64.2.0.567.18224.deb)
```

Configure:

```
export DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1   

git-credential-manager-core configure
```

Answer (score 0):

Install git on wsl Ubuntu

```
sudo apt install git
```

Set email and username

```
git config --global user.email "YOUR_EMAIL"
git config --global user.name "YOUR_USERNAME"
```

Install Git credentials manager

```
wget "https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/releases/download/v2.0.886/gcm-linux_amd64.2.0.886.deb" -O /tmp/gcmcore.deb
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/gcmcore.deb
git-credential-manager configure
```

Set credentials manager to read from cache

```
git config --global credential.credentialStore cache
```

Answer (score 0):

To use Git credential store on WSL (Ubuntu on Windows), you can follow these steps:

1. Configure the Windows Git credential helper by running the following command:

```bash
git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-credential-manager.exe"
```

2. Ensure that the HttpPath is used to prevent the error message "fatal: Cannot determine the organization name for this 'dev.azure.com' remote URL." You can do this by running the following command:

```bash
git config --global credential.useHttpPath true
```

By following these steps, you should be able to use the Git credential store on WSL (Ubuntu on Windows) successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I just bring over my `.gitconfig` from `C:/Users/[Myself]/.gitconfig` *(Windows)* to the git config file in Debian *(WSL)* which is located at `~/.gitconfig`.

You can also open both in the respective operating systems by using `git config --global --edit` as a command.

You *could* do some fancy linking of the files but what I do is just the simple and easy copying of the contents from my Windows system into my Linux system.

Both should end up looking at least like the following:

```
[user]
    name = YourName
    email = YourGitHubDetailStuffsIfYouUseGitHub@users.noreply.github.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-git) from Microsoft helped me.
Basicly says:

If GIT installed is **>= v2.39.0**

```
git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-credential-manager.exe"
```

else if GIT installed is **>= v2.36.1**

```
git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager.exe"
```

else if version is **< v2.36.1**

```
git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-credential-manager-core.exe"
```

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't get this working with `git-credential-manager.exe` on WSL2 with Debian. I'd always get `remote: Repository not found.` with no further error.
Instead I did the same with `git-credential-manager-core.exe` so my config is now `credential.helper=/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager-core.exe`. This worked right away, with GitHub 2FA/PAT set up on Windows before hand.

I have the following git versions:

- Windows:
  git version 2.31.0.windows.1
  Git Credential Manager for Windows v1.20.0.0
- Debian/WSL2
  git version 2.30.2