# Using different credentials for alternating repos with Microsoft Git-Credential-Manager

Tags: git, git-credential-manager

I'm using [Microsoft Git-Credential-Manager](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Mac-and-Linux/) for Linux (Ubuntu) for a couple weeks, with some credentials, and now I need to push modifications to a different repo with different credentials. But I can't do this, because GCM is trying to use incorrect data to access this repository.

How do I change these or add new ones in order to be able to commit to different repos with different credentials? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [git credential manager command to delete the entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553149/6309) for a given remote host.

```
git credential-manager reject <url>
```

Once the entry is deleted, you would be able to store new credentials.

You can store ([`git credential-manager store`](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/888)) one credential per host and user: that will be valid for all repos owned by said user.

For a credential per repository, as seen in  [Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issue 749](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/749#issuecomment-421430006), use (for Windows or Linux) the git config [`credential.useHttpPath`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-credentialuseHttpPath), explained [in git credentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials#Documentation/gitcredentials.txt-useHttpPath).

```
 git config --global credential.useHttpPath true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So isn't there a way to store more than one credential, like one per repo? Basically, I'll need to remove the old credentials every time I need to push to a different repository?

Comment: @darksoulsong You can, with `git credential-manager store`, as seen in https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/888 put one credential per host, ***and per user***. Just make sure your remote URL to which you are pushing includes the username `https::/username@github.com/username/myRepo.git`

Comment: @darksoulsong It should: the idea is the API (store/reject/approve/...) remains the same for any implementation of a `git credential-manager` command.

Comment: @darksoulsong You can also have one credential per repo, as seen in my edited answer. But I would still recommend to stick with one credential per user and server hostname.