# git symbolic-ref storage at central repo level

Tags: git, version-control, branch, alias, symbolic-references

Idea is to have dev_release_branch all time acting just as alias to latest release branch of that environment ( dev in this eg ).

And to have new branch created post every release by some convention & to update symb ref every time post completion of migration or release to respective en.

```
git symbolic-ref -m "Updating rel branch ref to new" dev_rel_3rd_Nov dev_release_branch
```

Would like to store both reference & its mapped name in central repository. Is there a way to achieve this as simple `git push HEAD:refs/for/dev_branch` fails

This is to support incremental release process & hence computing files changed would be easier by comparison of 2 branch names hashes..

Thanks!

Comment: To add,
`dev_branch` - will be one developers will work upon & push to mapped upstream origin/dev_branch
`dev_release_branch` - will be alias to what has been released to development environment ecosystem
`dev_rel_<date>` will be the one which gets created post every release & same needs to be updated to dev_release_branch with above scenario..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would like to store both reference & its mapped name in central repository.  Is there a way to achieve this ...

Not from a client over the Git protocols.

Also, `git symbolic-ref` is [a "plumbing" command (meant for scripts rather than casual use)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39847781/1256452), and as a consequence, it requires that you spell out the full reference, e.g.:

```
git symbolic-ref refs/heads/foo refs/heads/master
```

#### Why the answer is "no"

Let's create a proper symbolic reference, and try pushing it:

```
$ git branch xyz master
$ git symbolic-ref refs/heads/foo refs/heads/xyz
$ git push origin foo
To [url]
 * [new branch]      foo -> xyz
```

Now, over on the server for `origin`:

```
$ git branch
* master
  xyz
```

This is, I think, what you observed that led you to say:

> simple `git push HEAD:refs/for/dev_branch` fails

The problem here is that the `push` protocol literally has no way to push a symbolic reference.  The protocol consists of a series of requests to set reference names to specific hash IDs.  A symbolic reference is a reference that is set to a string that is *not* a hash ID.

This means that from a client, the only way to create a new symbolic reference on a server is to run Git commands directly on that server, e.g.:

```
ssh server "cd path/to/git/repo; git symbolic-ref ..."
```

The *fetch* protocol does allow retrieving symbolic references (in modern Git), but the push protocol does not allow setting them.

Answer (score 1):

As torek answered, it is not possible.

But it sounds like a XY problem anyway, to me.

Your actual problem seems to be solvable: just have a tag `dev_release_branch` and update that after each release (using `-f` on the `tag` and `push`). Then it is up to creative use of `git log`, `git show` or some script grepping through `.git/refs` to find the corresponding individual branch name.