# Access reflog subject with git rev-list (or any other plumbing command)

Tags: git, git-reflog, git-plumbing

I'd like to access reflog subjects with a plumbing command. I'd expect:

```sh
$ git rev-list --format='%gs' --walk-reflogs HEAD
```

to give me what I want, but this just gives me output like:

```
commit f1cb402488661fb3662ad876e98fcce991677333
commit 65e9bd51169e7f54f76edc9dbc926ec92af2fd7f
commit 1139b67c36f878a0e82e1dad141404ed7fb0923a
commit bea98a6a32477ad8e93929ac8d8f2ec66a9d3375
commit 9682247a229f2954820887212b7769a2a89ccd45
commit a73583bb74fd4d6db7bed6a6b61ba17be812e842
commit 96dbe20f02c58f6f5599495978e962a0ee285ce8
commit aba4a324c3f95ebebf8f3c8b2db3c89660a25ebe
commit 1139b67c36f878a0e82e1dad141404ed7fb0923a
commit f35aedc3594f9cb9dce5c89638d80e19c5f257b9
```

OTOH:

```sh
git reflog --format='%gs' HEAD
```

gives me what I'd expect.

Comment: I believe this post can help to understand more about plumbing commands https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847781/which-are-the-plumbing-and-porcelain-commands

Comment: What did you expect exactly?

Answer (score 1):

`git reflog` is a front end to `git log` (not to `git rev-list`).  While `git rev-list` is both a plumbing command, and a sister command to `git log`, it's not quite the equivalent of a plumbing version *of* `git log`.  In particular—just as you found—it has no nice way to access and format parts of commits.

The rather sad state of affairs is that there *is no plumbing version of `git log`*.  Perhaps, like `git status` has `--porcelain` to turn it *into* plumbing, `git log` needs `--porcelain`, so that we don't need to run `git -c log.decorate=... log.pretty=...` to override anything that might be in some user's `.gitconfig`.  (This is not meant to say that just the decorate and pretty settings need overriding: those were just the two I could think of off-hand here.  Oh, of course, pager as well.)