# Why does HEAD show up in `git branch --remote`?

Tags: git

When doing `git branch --all`, this:

```
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
```

both shows up, along with other branches. What is the first line for? I thought, the HEAD is just a ref that points to the latest commit of a branch. So why is there one single HEAD on the remote server that points to master, instead of multiple HEADs, one for each branch?

Comment: The HEAD on a remote is the default branch of the remote. It is the branch you will check out when you clone it.

Comment: That's confusing, that HEAD means different things remotely and locally. Thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: It does not mean different things. If you clone a local repo you will also clone HEAD

Answer (score 3):

## Summary

My advice is to ignore this entry.  You don't care about it, so ... don't care about it.

## Long

Every Git repository *must* have a `HEAD` setting.  The `HEAD` in a normal repository—the kind in which you do your own work, for instance—stores the *current branch name*, or else the repository is in what Git calls *detached HEAD* mode and `HEAD` stores the *current commit hash ID* as a raw big-ugly-hash-ID.  So `HEAD` in this kind of repository represents the *currently checked out commit*.  As there is always—well, *almost* always—a currently checked out commit, Git can simply read `HEAD` to find out which branch name or hash ID locates that commit.<sup>1</sup>

But even in a "bare" clone, which does not have a currently-checked-out commit—it has no *working tree* so that it literally *can't* have a checked out commit—Git still requires that `HEAD` exist, and contain a branch name.  That name represents the *default branch name*, as [Kim noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74561949/why-does-head-show-up-in-git-branch-remote#comment131618055_74561949).  This should be the name of some branch that does exist in that repository.<sup>2</sup>  The point of this default branch name is simple: you, as a client, will run:

```
git clone ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git
```

for example, or a similar `git clone` request to some other URL, perhaps on GitHub or perhaps elsewhere.  You *can* add:

```
-b somebranch
```

to tell your `git clone` operation that it should do a `git switch soembranch` immediately after cloning: that will be the (only) actual *branch name* in your new clone.  But if you don't bother with the `-b` option—and most people mostly don't—your own Git software will ask the hosting site's Git software: *Say, which branch name do you recommend?*  The answer that comes back is the branch name stored in the `HEAD`.<sup>3</sup>

The point of doing all this is simple enough.  Git *can* work with *no branch names at all*.  Git does not actually *need* branch names.  Git only needs commits and their big ugly hash IDs.  It's us *humans*, not Git, who need branch names: the hash IDs are too big and ugly for us.  But when you make a new clone, Git turns all the original repository's *branch* names into your own *remote-tracking* names: their `main` or `master` becomes your `origin/main` or `origin/master`, for instance.  That creates room for you to have *your* branch names, which may well hold different big-ugly-hash-IDs.

So, when you first clone some existing Git repository—let's say it is one with four branch names in it—you'll have four remote-tracking names, one for each of the original repository's branch names.  You will have zero of *your own* branch names.  That's not a good start, because humans don't work well without the names.  So the *last* step of `git clone` is to *create* one new branch name, in your new clone, and then switch to that branch name by checking out the right commit.  Which commit is the *right* commit?  Well, obviously,<sup>4</sup> it's the commit obtained by using the corresponding remote-tracking name:

- They have branches `br1`, `br2`, `br3`, and `main`.
- Their `br2` means commit `c3ff4cec66ec004d884507f5296ca2a323adbbc5`.
- Therefore your `origin/br2` means commit `c3ff4cec66ec004d884507f5296ca2a323adbbc5`.
- Therefore, if you said `-b br2`, the *correct* commit hash ID for your newly created `br2` branch is `c3ff4cec66ec004d884507f5296ca2a323adbbc5`.

If you *didn't* say `-b br2`, your Git asks their Git which of the four names they recommend, and as long as they don't come back and give your Git a wrong one like `master` (see footnote 2 and Google hosting), your Git can use the corresponding `origin/main` or `origin/br1` or whatever that your Git just created to get the right hash ID.

---

<sup>1</sup>The *almost always* case occurs when the repository is on what Git calls an *orphan branch*.  Here, `HEAD` still contains a *branch name*, but it's the name of a branch that does not yet exist.

<sup>2</sup>If the `HEAD` of a bare repository contains the name of a branch that does not yet exist, that bare repository is "on" an orphan branch, as noted in footnote 1.  This is not harmful to the bare repository, but it does mean that when you use `git clone` to *clone* the bare repository, the *other* Git software gets, from the bare clone, the name of a branch that doesn't exist.  That *other* Git software—on the client that's making the clone—then tries to check out that branch by its name, and can't, because there is no such name.  This causes the *client* Git to spit out some annoying error messages, confusing the users *at* the client end.  Hence the advice that the bare repository contain the name of a branch that does exist, here.

Web hosting sites like Bitbucket, GitHub, and GitLab *must* provide some way—some hosting-provider specific method—for you to set the "default branch", as there's nothing built in to the Git push protocol to do this.  If they don't provide that, you may be stuck with an unwanted branch name.  Google, for some reason, fail to provide such a way, and you're stuck with having to name a branch `master` or else have client clones produce this annoying message.  It doesn't mean you *can't* use the hosting service, but it sure is annoying.

<sup>3</sup>If the hosting site has a detached HEAD, or is running a truly ancient Git server, there's no way for it to provide a branch name here.  In that case, your own local Git software can fall back on a compiled-in default name, and if even *that* doesn't work, it will complain and not check anything out after all, printing out an annoying message instead.  You will be forced to run your own `git checkout` or `git switch` command to create the first and only-so-far branch in your new repository.  See also footnote 2.

<sup>4</sup>It's clearly obvious to everyone who's been using Git for a decade, which makes it obvious and trivial like in your typical math proof.  See also [this list of proof techniques](https://users.cs.northwestern.edu/%7Eriesbeck/proofs.html).

---

#### OK, but what does this have to do with `origin/HEAD`?

Let's now look at `origin`: `origin` is the *remote* name, and is the source of the `origin/` part in `origin/br1`, `origin/br2`, `origin/br3`, and `origin/main`.<sup>5</sup>  The name `origin`, stored in your `.git/config` (which you can look at, or even edit, if you like—it's a plain-text file—just be careful when editing it!)—serves a number of functions.  The *primary* two, which are always there immediately upon the creation of a remote like `origin`, are these:

- It stores a *url*, so that `git fetch origin` knows where to reach the other Git software.
- It stores a *default fetch refspec*, so that `git fetch origin` knows which *names* to create or update in your own repository.  Using `--single-branch` at `git clone` time alters this default fetch refspec.

We won't go into any detail on the fetch refspec here, and aren't too worried about the URL either, but I'll note that if the URL changes, it's easy to edit `.git/config` and fix it.  You can do this instead of using `git remote set-url origin new-url`, as long as you're careful to use an editor that preserves the `.git/config` file format (a modified [INI format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file); must be saved as UTF-8).

In effect, then, `origin` represents the *other Git repository:* the one you just cloned.  That's why you have *remote-tracking names:* each one represents a *branch name in that other repository*.

Your own Git has its own `HEAD`, but if that other Git over at `origin` is a repository—and it must be, because you just cloned it—then it too must have its own `HEAD`, representing the "default branch" in that repository.  The authors of Git decided that it would make sense to copy their `HEAD` to your `origin/HEAD`.

Now, the *mechanism* by which `HEAD` contains a branch name—assuming, of course, that `HEAD` *does* contain a branch name, which gets us right back to footnotes 2 and 3 when we're talking about the server-side Git repository—is what Git calls a *symbolic reference*.  So your own Git software uses another symbolic reference in *your* clone to represent the symbolic reference that, we assume, exists in the `origin` clone.  If they have `HEAD -> main`, then, *you* should have `origin/HEAD -> origin/main`.  If they have `HEAD -> master`, *you* should have `origin/HEAD -> origin/master`.

Your Git (your software working with your repository) simply re-creates the adjusted symbolic reference that your Git assumes their Git has, based on the default-branch information your Git got from their Git.  And that's what your `origin/HEAD` represents after `git clone`.

---

<sup>5</sup>You can, if you like, use some name other than `origin`.  You can also, or instead, add *more* remotes to your clone after the first standard `origin` remote.  But we won't get into these details here.

---

#### But what *use* is `origin/HEAD`?

None.

Okay, that's not really true: the correct answer is *almost none*.

You *can* **change** the symbolic reference stored in your own `origin/HEAD` any time you like, using:

```
git remote set-head origin <name>
```

You can *delete* `origin/HEAD` using:

```
git remote set-head --delete origin
```

You can have your Git call up the `origin` Git software, as if doing the initial clone, and ask them what their `HEAD` is *now* and have your Git update your `origin/HEAD` appropriately with:

```
git remote set-head --auto origin
```

This lets you *change* your own `origin/HEAD` to whatever you like, which may not be the same as what they actually have in their `HEAD`.  Git's rule here is a little odd, but does make sense, sort of: all your `origin/*` names are *yours*, they're just *automatically* matched up to theirs by default, except that you have to manually use `--auto` to automatically match up `origin/HEAD`...?

But what good is something that you can set, if you can't *query* it?  Well, that's where the real weirdness comes in.  You *can* query it, in several ways:

- You can run `git branch -r` or `git branch -a` and *see* it.  What good is that?  I don't know, perhaps you can come up with something.
- You can run `git rev-parse` to *read* it, in one of three ways; see below.
- Last, you can use the word `origin`, naked like this, to read it ... *sometimes*.  Sometimes, the word `origin` means the *remote*.  Sometimes, it means `origin/HEAD`.  When does it mean which?  That's the tricky part.

#### Using `git rev-parse`

As noted above, what Git really needs, to get its Gitty bits of dirty-work done, are hash IDs.  Branch names—and other names like tag names—are just clever methods by which Git allows us humans to use human-oriented names to *find* the hash IDs.

The `git rev-parse` command is a general purpose *plumbing command*<sup>6</sup> in Git that lets you do the same things other Git commands do, to work with branch and tag and other names.  Because it's a very central Git command, it does a lot of other things too; we're only going to worry on the branch and remote-tracking name oriented ones here.  We will run it like this:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name origin/HEAD
refs/remotes/origin/master
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref origin/HEAD
origin/master
```

These show two ways to examine the actual `origin/HEAD` in a clone of the Git repository for Git.  As you can see from the above, in my clone, `origin/HEAD` is a symbolic name for `origin/master` (whose *full* name is `refs/remotes/origin/master`, but we can usually abbreviate as just `origin/master`).

To get the *hash ID* of `origin/master`, we can again use `git rev-parse`:

```
$ git rev-parse origin/master
c000d916380bb59db69c78546928eadd076b9c7d
```

So `rev-parse` can find the raw hash ID of a commit, turning a name—a branch name like `main` or `master`, or a remote-tracking name like `origin/master`—into a commit hash ID.  That's what has happened here.  But suppose I give `git rev-parse` the name `origin`?  That's not a *branch* name, not a *tag* name, and not even a remote-tracking name.  Let's try it:

```
$ git rev-parse origin
c000d916380bb59db69c78546928eadd076b9c7d
```

Let's try this too:

```
$ git rev-parse origin/HEAD
c000d916380bb59db69c78546928eadd076b9c7d
```

OK, this last one makes sense: `origin/HEAD` is a remote-tracking name that is a symbolic reference to `origin/master`, which in turn means `c000d916380bb59db69c78546928eadd076b9c7d`.  But why did `origin`, without `/HEAD` or `/master` or whatever added, *also* turn into `c000d916380bb59db69c78546928eadd076b9c7d`?

The answer is in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), which lists a six-step process for resolving a potentially ambiguous name.  If we give the string `zog` to `git rev-parse`, is that a *branch* name?  Is it a *tag* name?  Is it a remote-tracking name ... well, it's definitely *not* a remote tracking name, as those have both a remote and a name, and `zog` has no slash in it.  But to answer the question of what kind of name it is and whether it's valid at all—maybe it's just an error—`git rev-parse` goes through the six steps listed.  Follow the link above and scroll down a little until you see the text that begins with:

> `<refname>, e.g. master, heads/master, refs/heads/master`
> A symbolic ref name. ...

Read through the six steps.  Note that step 6 reads:

> 6. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD` if it exists.

Note carefully the *order* of the six steps.  Step 3 mentions `refs/tags/<refname>`; `refs/heads/<refname>` is later, at step 4.  This means that if `zog` is *both* a tag *and* a branch name, `git rev-parse` will use the *tag* name!

This is in fact true of *most* Git commands.  The `git branch` and `git switch` commands are some of the big exceptions here: they know, or at least assume, that you're probably giving them a *branch* name, so they generally try names as branch names *before* trying them in any other way.

This fact—that tag names take priority, except when they don't—is one of several reasons to *avoid* having, e.g., `zog` be *both* a branch name *and* a tag name.  Git is a computer, following precise rules in a precise order—but each Git command can have *different* rules, so while Git won't get them mixed up, you, as a human, probably will.

In any case, the fact that step 6 exists, and if given `origin` will look for `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`, means that you can—in *some* places—use the name `origin` by itself to *mean* `origin/HEAD`, which in turn *means* whatever name `origin/HEAD` is a symbolic reference for.  So that's a way you can use `origin`.  But sometimes, when you use `origin`, Git will treat that as a *remote*, rather than as a name to resolve through `git rev-parse`.  As a human who can get confused about when a dual-use `zog`-branch-and-`zog`-tag gets used as a branch name or as a tag name, you as a human can also get confused about when `origin` as a name gets used as a remote name, and when it's turned into `origin/HEAD`.  So just don't do that.

---

<sup>6</sup>Git divides its commands (not always entirely successfully) into "plumbing" commands that do some low-level task and "porcelain" commands that users run.  A "porcelain" command might be implemented by three or more "plumbing" commands plus some kind of nicer user interface.  The original `git commit` worked this way, for example.  See [What does the term "porcelain" mean in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6976473/1256452) and [Which are the plumbing and porcelain commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39847781/1256452)

---

## Conclusion

The above is really just a very long way to go into the fact that Git has all kinds of fancy stuff that you probably shouldn't use because it's a bad idea.  Don't use these esoteric methods of working *unless* they solve some *very specific problem you have* that you can't solve some other, clearer way.  This whole thing is almost certainly a bad idea.  Git has to keep supporting it for backwards compatibility, but you don't have to use it.  Don't use it.

Comment: Yes. The takeaway is that git is wacky powerful, to the point you can make some bold mistakes.